# How can I use eval for conditional feature call with parameters?

Tags: karate

I wanted to call another feature file in a feature file with parameters but if a data value of previous api's response is true. And after running this eval function I wanted to it continue to run other parts of my main feature. I wrote this code;

- eval if (response.data.eula == true) karate.call('classpath:eula/eula-sign.feature') { no: '#(no)' , password: '#(password)'}

But I can't use eval like this. How can I achieve my aim that I explained above?

I've tried conditional logic methods which explained in Karate intuit page. But I couldn't solve my problem.

- eval if (response.data.eula == true) karate.call('classpath:eula/eula-sign.feature') { no: '#(no)' , password: '#(password)'}

As I expect error, Karate gave me these logs;
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: content-filter.feature:26 - javascript evaluation failed: if (response.data.eula == true) ; karate.call('classpath:eulasign/eula-sign.feature') { no: '#(no)' , password: '#(password)'}, :1:135 Expected ; but found {
if (response.data.eula == true) ; karate.call('classpath:eulasign/eula-sign.feature') { no: '#(no)' , password: '#(password)'}
                                                                                                                                       ^ in  at line number 1 at column number 135

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `karate.call` and `call read`.
It's either `karate.call(fileName, [arg])` or `call read(filename) { arg }`

So in your case with karate.call, the variables `no` and `password` have to be passed in JSON format as the second argument of your function.